# Implementing JSON ShouldSerialize in WebAPI

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a C# POCO that looks like the following

```
public class Notice
{
    public bool ShouldSerializeUserId { get;set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeLogin { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }

    public string Message { get;set; }
}
```

I need to be able to hide and show UserId and Login properties based on certain condition and return them as JSON in WebAPI. However, somehow the WebAPI JsonSerializer does not honor ShouldSerialize property. How to make this code below to work ? I am using ASP.NET 5.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;

public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        List<Notice> notices = NoticeRepository.GetNotices();
        //need to show or hide UserId or Login here...
        return Json(notices);
    }
}
```

Comment: You tagged your question [tag:asp.net-web-api] but your code seems to be from [tag:asp.net-mvc].  For which are you seeking an answer?  They use different JSON serializers.

Comment: @dbc, I am specifically seeking for answer to web-api, however in ASP.NET 5, both web-api and mvc distinction are combined together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you need to use `ShouldSerialize**` [method](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm), not the property.

Something like:

```
public class Notice
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeUserId ()
    {
        return // your condition;
    }

    public string Login { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeLogin  ()
    {
        return // your condition;
    }

    public string Message { get;set; }
}
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Web API uses reflection to call **ShouldSerialize* methods** to determine ***(not property)*** if specific public properties should be serialized.

For example,

```
private bool _shouldSerializeUserId;
// You can this method to set value.
public void SetShouldSerializeUserId(bool shouldSerializeUserId)
{
   _shouldSerializeUserId = shouldSerialize;
}
public bool ShouldSerializeUserId()
{
   return _shouldSerializeUserId;
}
```